# Is it possible to pass a callback to a webworker?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I have a render worker that I would like to pass a callback to. I know that the worker.postMessage method now supports Javascript Objects, but when I try to pass a function withing the object I get an error telling me that it "couldn't clone" the object.

I also tried JSON.stringify() on the object, and learned that functions don't get stringified because JSON doesn't support function scope.

Is there a way to pass a callback to a Web Worker? If not, how would you suggest working around the limitation?

My issue is that I send the worker a message to start the rendering at the same time I start an animation. So I need to wait until BOTH are finished before executing the "callback"

Comment: Can you show some code? A [mcve] would be nice

Comment: I'm not sure what code you want to see? I just need to know if there's any way of passing a function to a web worker. A JSON string won't work due to scope, and passing an object literal throws an exception. What code are you looking for exactly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there a way to pass a callback to a Web Worker?

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage):

> The postMessage() method of the Worker interface sends a message to the worker's inner scope. This accepts a single parameter, which is the data to send to the worker. The data may be any value or **JavaScript object handled by the structured clone algorithm**, which includes cyclical references.

And [also](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm):

> Things that don't work with structured clones
>
> - Error and Function objects cannot be duplicated by the structured clone algorithm; attempting to do so will throw a DATA_CLONE_ERR exception.

So **No**. You can't pass functions about.

> My issue is that I send the worker a message to start the rendering at the same time I start an animation. So I need to wait until BOTH are finished before executing the "callback"

Generate a unique ID (e.g. a timestamp concatenated with a random number). Store it. Associate whatever data you like (including the function you want to use as a callback). Pass it to your end of animation handler and the web worker.

Send that ID back when the work is finished. Listen for events with that ID in them, and look it up in your data structure.

Comment: What is hilarious is that I JUST finished doing exactly what you suggested before reading your answer. Thank you very much for the snippets and the links, that cleared that right up for me. I had read the first snippet from MDN, but the second one is what put things into perspective.